# Use special characters in resource files xml (Android)

Tags: android, xml, character

I'm trying to get some strings into a string-array to be printed to a TextView, however whenever I try to compile my application I get an error: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f040001`. I'm a noob but I think that means I need to change the string-array items because they have a special character. How do I put a special character into a string-array item so I can print it out. This is an example of the type of string in my array - `<item>nos réserves</item>`.

Comment: I don't see a special character in "nos réserves".  Post the code you use to access the string array.

Comment: Surely the "é" is a special character? The code that uses it is - `random.setText(stringArray[randNum]);` . random is a TextView item and randNum is a randomly generated number between 0 and the number of strings in the array.

Comment: No.  That is just a character from a non-English language.  There are many of those in many different languages.  Special characters are things like !*#)(%&#.  Or in other words they are characters that could mean something in HTML or XML.